# Apply styles on inserted manualy div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the string with tags in db field, which looks like this:

```
<div class="blockquote" id="quote11"><a>Admin</a>Hello</div> <br>Hello!
```

So I get this from db and put it on the page like this:

```
<div class="comment-content" id="@mydivId">
    @comment.Comment
</div>
```

after which i do this:

```
window.onload = function () {...    
  var text = $("#" + id).text().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
  var parsedtext = $.parseHTML(text);
  $("#"+id).html(parsedtext);
}
```

This is needed because without this the page will render wrong chars.
But now there is a problem: my styles from external "styles.css" file dont apply on inserted div.

Is there any workout from this trouble?

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7L8o1u3/34/) but it will not help much because to show this trouble razor component is required.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? The replacements with regex seem redundant given your input string.

Comment: with out this i will get this codes on my page as text. parseHtml dont understand this codes so this will cause error. I`m attempting to insert the div with all styles.

Comment: You need to provide an actual code sample that reproduce the issue you describe, as from what we see now it is not possible to detect why it is not working

Comment: have you tried adding the css file at the end? I also had this before and when I debugged it, it was because my html was read then my css was added to this and afterwards I added the new element so it didn't add the css anymore.

Comment: @LGSon, i addded jsfiddle. hope it will help.

Comment: @mrdeadsven, mmm...It`s a partial view inside partial view kinda. and the styles are adding on the very top - on a layout.

Comment: @Arc_75 seems to me in your JSfiddle that you apply css on classes, but on your inserted div's have other classes then the ones you already have? or is this just because the JSfiddle is incomplete?

Comment: @mrdeadsven why? css have .blockquote and i insert blockquote class.

Comment: @Arc_75 ahh ok now I get the code sorry my bad was looking at it the wrong way. Okay can you debug it looking at 1) what classes the inserted div's have? 2) as I suggested first how everything is loaded in, whether your css sheet is added before your insert or not? Because I still believe these could be the problem.

Comment: @Arc_75 I have check your code. First, it must add jQuery library in Javascript, not "No Library - Pure JS". Then you must declare the variable "text" and assign some value. After all, everything is fine. Here a fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7L8o1u3/32/

Comment: @mrdeadsven, yes. every classes and id`s are on place. it just dont associate it with the classes in styles.css file and dont apply this styles for that class. But the code itself appends after page loaded. what will change if i put the styles on the bottom of page?

Comment: @PieterP., mm yes. sorry, didnt notice that i removed some necessery part. Edited the main question with the edited link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by remaking `@Styles.Render()` order.
For me all the renders were in layout at the very top and the styles renders first.
I made the render local for this page and put it in the very end of the page as @mrdeadsven suggested. 
Thanks for help.